Uniqueness theorem of meromorphic functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be meromorphic on a connected subset $\Omega$ of $\Bbb C$. If there exists a sequence $\left\{z_n\right\}$ of $\Omega$ such that $f\left(z_n\right)=g\left(z_n\right)$, and  $\left\{z_n\right\}$ has a limit point in $\Omega$, then $f(z) \equiv g(z)$ . If $f,g$ has just isolated singularities, the above statement is false, how can we find a counterexample?

My attempt: Let $F=f-g$, then $F(z_n)=0$, and $F$ has only at most countable poles. Let $z_n\to z_0\in \Omega$,
if $F$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, then $F(z_0)=0$, but we could not use the uniquness result of holomorphic function, since $F$ is just meromorphic...Oh.
if $z_0$ is a pole of $F$, then contradicts with the isolated singularity, OK?
If $F$ has just isolated singularities, then...

Consider $\Omega = \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and the functions
\begin{align*}
& f(z) = \tan{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)} \\
& g(z) = \sin{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)} \\
\end{align*}
and the sequence $z_n = (n\pi)^{-1}$, then $f(z_n) = g(z_n)$, but $f \neq g$.
